# How to create multiple user accounts in Bash?

Tags: unix, sh

I have two scripts (I shall rename to a.sh and b.sh), and those scripts query information from a website. Their functionality is to look over the website and print out a user's information. My a.sh script calls the b.sh script.

Is there a way I can put these two scripts in a bash script and have them run at once? I have been reading up on this and saw suggestions to use nohup. When I made some random practice tests, it worked perfectly. But when I brought in my other scripts, it tells me that there is no such file or directory.

I had copied my files into a new directory. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

./a.sh
./b.sh

for i in $( ./a.sh ); do 
    nohup sh ./UserU.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null &
done
```

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If `a.sh` calls `b.sh`, why do you need to run them both separately in this script?

Comment: You're running `a.sh` twice: first when you just do `./a.sh`, then again when you do `for i in $( ./a.sh)`. Is that really what you want? Why doesn't the loop use `$i` anywhere?

Comment: You don't need to use `nohup` to run multiple commands at once. That's used to allow a background command to keep running after you logout. Just run the first command in the background and start the second command.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with creating user accounts, as said in your title?

Comment: Because I want this script to call both at once. I want a script where I can get multiple user information at once, instead of going user by user.

Comment: The question is tagged `bash`, but you use `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Sorry changed that to sh. Let me clarify. If the user exists, then it will query the website for the user information. If not, it will allow the user to be created. I was wondering if there was a way or a method to get multiple user information at once. If using a for or while loop or which method would work.

Answer (score 0):

If `a.sh` prints out the list of usernames, you can do:

```
for user in $(./a.sh); do
    sh ./UserU.sh "$user" </dev/null &>/dev/null &
done
```

You don't need to use `nohup`, just run them in the background with `&`. Pass the iteration variable as a parameter to the `UserU.sh` script to make it process that user.

Comment: Thanks, will try this